# I just got +100 rep on the main site

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I got +100 rep randomly. When I looked in my reputation changes, it said it was for an 'association bonus'. My rep on Stack Overflow recently hit 200, meaning I got a bonus of 100 on meta. Why does this mean I get +100 on Stack Overflow?

Comment: You know, sometimes it's best to keep quiet about these uhh.. pleasant surprises.. if you know what I mean heh heh ;D

Comment: You get 100 on *all* sites.

Comment: @l46kok Yes, it was a very pleasant surprise, made my day already :)

Comment: From the linked faq: *you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: +100 **on each site** (awarded a maximum of one time per site)*

Comment: Ah...I see. If one of u had answered like that, I would have upvoted and accepted your answer :)